# Is there any way to get a character with these class levels using retraining?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, multi-classing, character-levels, retraining

I am wondering if there is any way one can become a Wizard 1, Mage of the third eye 10, Evangelist 9 by using the [retraining rules](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/more-character-options/retraining/)

If yes, would you have to  get 1 wizard, 4 in another class and then retrain away the other class, or could you retrain away wizard after starting on mage of the third eye?

Comment: Hmm, "until you meet the qualifications again." sounds like it might be a loophole in that you can use a prestige class to qualify for another.

Comment: For example if you are wizard 5, mage of the third eye 10, evangalist 5. Then you would still be well the requirements for both perstige classes even if you retrain away 1 wizard level.

Comment: "A wizard may know any number of spells. "

Comment: Note: You could always go Wizard 9/Mage of the Third Eye 1/Evangelist 10 and align evangelist with MoTE, thus getting the capstones of both prestige classes.

Comment: I had not thought about that, good take.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## No.

Per the [Retraining FAQ](https://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1gn#v5748eaic9r9e):

> Retraining: Can I retrain out of my base classes and use my prestige class levels to meet the requirements for that prestige class?
>
> No.
>
> The retraining rules say, "If retraining a class level means you no longer qualify for a feat, prestige class, or other ability you have, you can't use that feat, prestige class, or ability until you meet the qualifications again." Therefore, if you retrain out of the base class and that causes you to no longer meet the requirements of the prestige class, you no longer have access to the class features from that prestige class, and therefore can't use that prestige class to meet the requirements of anything (including itself).
>
> Update 10/16/13: In any case, you cannot use rule elements from a prestige class to meet the requirements of that prestige class.
>
> Update 10/16/13: New ruling: **You cannot use retraining to replace a base class level with a prestige class level.**

Since there are no prestige classes you can qualify for with a single level of a non-prestige class, you cannot take a prestige class as your second level. This means that you'd be unable to retrain your second level into the wanted prestige class, preventing you from using the retraining rules to be a Wizard 1/Mage of the Third Eye 10/Evangelist 9.